# flutter textfield extra space

Tags: flutter, dart

Implemented a flutter chat app where the bottom `TextField` for writing messages takes extra space when the keyboard opens. Found a possible solution to avoid double `Scaffold`. But for some reason, that's not possible. Is anyone here to suggest me another way to solve that issue?

[image]

Comment: please share minimalistic code, so we can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
isDense: true,
```

add the above lines in your `TextFormField`